# How to get product image full file path directory in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, directory, filesystem

I have a custom extension that needs the full path directory file of the product image not the URL of the product image, for example:

```
/var/www/Mage2Dir/pub/media/catalog/product/d/i/base_image_product.jpg
```

how can i achieve this if i have only product id?

Comment: in which file you need this code as in list.phtml and detail page its already there

Comment: @ParulThakkar in custom model file , i need to read the full image path so i can modify the image

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
$directory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead('media');
        $fullImagePath = $directory->getAbsolutePath($this->mediaConfig->getMediaPath($product->getThumbnail()));
```

For this, you need to inject below class in your constructor

```
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
    /** 
     * @var Config
     */
    private $mediaConfig;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private $filesystem;


    /**
     * @param Config $mediaConfig
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     */

     public function __construct(
            Config $mediaConfig,
            Filesystem $filesystem
        )
        {
            $this->mediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
            $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        }
```

Hope this will work
Thanks.